# Multithreading and locks on Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have 3 different processes taking turns randomly to execute their code.

Process 1: produce a letter.

Process 2: produce a number.

Process 3: consume last character produced.

I need to be able to see how the string is being manipulated by those processes, I tried to do it multithreading but I can only see the string updating every three "turns".

How can I "lock" each thread so it can't run if another one is already running?

This is my main method

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {   
                ventanaPrincipal frame = new ventanaPrincipal();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Constructor

```
public ventanaPrincipal() {

    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setEditable(false);
    textField.setBounds(10, 88, 414, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 119, 106, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    hilo1 = new Thread(this);
    hilo2 = new Thread(this);
    hilo3 = new Thread(this);
    hilo1.start();
    hilo2.start();
    hilo3.start();
}
```

Run method

```
public void run() {
    while (bandera3 == 0) { 
    Thread ct = Thread.currentThread();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }   
    if(ct == hilo1 && bandera1 < 20){
            lblNewLabel.setText("Turno: " + turno);
            cadena = cadena.concat("" + productorLetras());//produce letter
            textField.setText(cadena);
            turno++;
        }
    if(ct == hilo2 && bandera2 < 20) {
            lblNewLabel.setText("Turno: " + turno); 
            cadena = cadena.concat("" + productorNumeros());//produce number
            textField.setText(cadena);
            turno++;
        }
    if(ct == hilo3 && cadena.length() > 0){
            lblNewLabel.setText("Turno: " + turno);
            consumidor();//consume
            textField.setText(cadena);
            turno++;
            }
        if(bandera1 >= 20 && bandera2 >= 20 && cadena.length() == 0){
            bandera3 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the problem is, that the changes are done too fast to be visible. You start all 3 Threads directly after each other and all have the same "timeout" with 1000 ms. Try to change the waiting time to a random amount, for example:

```
Thread.sleep(1000 * Math.random());
```

But you still have the problem, that your code is not multi-threading save. You need to have some kind of synchronization mechanism to avoid race conditions.

P.S. Maybe just another little hint: I would create for every Thread a new Runnable and do not reuse the same with a switch/several if statements. It makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your run method to something like (This will synchronize the UI changes to the event thread) :

```
while (bandera3 == 0) { 
   final Thread ct = Thread.currentThread();
   try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   } 
   EventQueue.invokeAndWait( new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           // your if statements go here.
       }
   });
}
```

although all of this seems kind of sketchy. For example, I would suggest creating a separate `Runnable` class for each type of operation and not doing conditionals based on equivalence of the current `Thread` to a field.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you doing with these if statements but i would use different Runnable implementations, maybe with an inline class like :

```
hilo1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
//Override Runnable
}
```

and you should use the statement synchronized(or synchronized blocks) on fields that are used by more then one thread like :

```
synchronized(turno){
       // do stuff with turno that are critical 
}
```

Here an good link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

And Object.wait() and Object.notify() maybe  good keywords for the case that you want to consume but there is nothing left.